# Filter JSON - Get values which are non empty

Tags: json, excel, power-automate

When I read row from Excel I get a response in JSON:

```
body: {
    "1": "",
    "2": "X",
    "3": "Y",
    "4": "",
    ...
}
```

One row represents one year - 365 days where each day may contain some one-letter info (X, Y, Z..) or `""` - the problem is that now I have to access all 365 days which takes quite a long time.

I would need to access only those which `!= ""`, is there any possibility how to do it? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Where do you get this? On a sheet or VBA?

Comment: Sheet -> Table..

Comment: Can you post a screencapture of that.

Comment: Added screen of table

Comment: I don't understand how that relates to the code block. Where is the X and Y?

Comment: That code block was just an example of how that object looks like, in this case, I would have X in the D cell under 2.I and Y in the E cell under 3.I , don't understand why does that matter

Answer (score 1):

### Use expressions with the xpath() and xml() functions to parse the data, and then reparse that natively in Power Automate.

*I'll kindly suggest that I think that whomever you're working this solution for is perhaps not in an ideal place processing this data in excel. It would be better placed in a SharePoint list, or some kind of database, as you're storing the data for subsequent processing. Once there, these kinds of difficulties will be far less common.*

The following flow will get what you need:

[image]

This flow is based upon [John Liu's excellent Power Automate XML hack](http://johnliu.net/blog/2017/11/foreach-property-in-microsoftflow-json-with-xpath-microblog), which (after the flow has prepared it) converts the JSON object into XML. I recommend reading that to gain an understanding of the steps here.

Once the XML has been interrogated for the field name, and value, and that placed into a new array (in the Select action) then it can be filtered to non-empty values. From that point you can process however you like.

---

Details:

1. **rootification** - this places the object within a structure the `xpath()` function can parse.
2. **xmlify** - this converts the object into an XML string using the `xml()` and `xpath()` functions.
3. **Select for JSON array** - This creates a new array using the field name, and field value, from the xml. I'll break this step down
   later.
4. **Filter array** - this uses `item()['Value']` to check the results from the fields you created. Anything that is not blank will be in
   the final array it creates.

Numbers 1, 2, and 3, can be combined into the 'From' field if you wish to clean out actions:

```
xpath(xml(json(concat('{ "root": ', string(variables('excel')), ' }'))), '/root/*')
```

[image]

On the Select for JSON array action:

```
if(startsWith(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')), '_x003'), if(equals(length(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)'))), 7), substring(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')), 5, 1), concat(substring(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')), 5, 1), substring(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')), 7))), string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')))
```

The important part to concentrate on in all that is within the true branch - `xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')` - where the `xpath()` function will pull the name of a field from the XML.

The first layer of the nested if/then structure checks whether the XML field name begins with "_x003" (I assume it indicates integer/number), if it begins with that then it will perform the next paragraph, otherwise it will simply return the field name as a string.

The second layer looks at numeric field names, so if you simply used `xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')` in there then for field '1' that will provide "**x0003**1****" as a result. The "1" between the "3" and that last underscore is the field name. When you reach double characters (of any kind) it places the next character *after* that final underscore. So the rest of the formula above is a one size fits all approach (for anyone reading) that will process whatever is in that field name into the JSON. *I will break that down if requested.*

```
xpath(item(),'string(//*)')
```

The `'Value'` field uses `xpath()` to pull the value from each item in the XML previously generated.

Comment: Thanks, Really Needed that Decoding part, as it was ruining my data ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## Non-XML Approaches

There are two ways to do this which don't involve using the XML approach (which still needs to handle that excel data), both of which are bespoke to your particular situation. The former will be more malleable.

---

### Import the Table into a SharePoint List and Process

Use the flow to grab the data, and just put it straight into a SharePoint list using the "*Create an item in SharePoint for a selected row*" template.

This assumes that you already have a list with all the requisite fields available in SharePoint. However, if you don't you can look up creating a list from an Excel table and that should have you up and running relatively quickly (with some tinkering after creation).

No-one has to know that the SharePoint list even exists, but you can use it as a worker to process changes or additions to the Excel data.

---

### Cycle Days of the Year and Pull Fields Respectively.

Alternatively you could pull an Excel field for each day of the year, based on a separate array that holds the numbers 1-365 (and another array for leap years), which will be easier to understand, but not useful for similar data.

This approach uses zero XML trickery, the flipside is that this is bespoke to your specific fieldnames.

Again, advice would be having the data elsewhere.

---

The image is at the end.

First define the following variables:

1. `yearOrLeapVAR` - Object - Contains two arrays:

   - `year` - 1-365 - A normal year.
   - `leapYear` - 1-366 - A leap year.
2. `isLeapVAR` - Boolean - Indicates if the year is a leap year ([explanation](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Leap-Years/m-p/914251#M128493)).

   ```
   equals(formatDateTime(addDays(concat(formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy'), '-02-01T00:00:00.0000000Z'), 28), 'MMM'), 'Feb')
   ```
3. `relevantDaysVAR` - Array - Empty
4. `yearVAR` - Array - Empty
5. `isEmptyVAR` - Boolean (*Optional*) - If you wish to separate confirmation that a value is empty you can use this to run your condition from later.

Then you need to process the data, all Parse JSON Steps are optional, but they allow future Power Automate users that may not understand functions within expressions to more easily understand what is happening.

1. **Define the `yearVAR` Array.** - Using a condition action dependent on whether it is a leap year or not define the contents of the yearVAR using either:

   - **Leap Year** - `body('Parse_JSON_yearOrLeapVAR')?['leapYear']`
   - **Normal Year** - `body('Parse_JSON_yearOrLeapVAR')?['year']`
2. **For Each day in the Year Extract the Respective Value.** - Within an Apply to each action, using a condition, look at `variables('excel')[items('Apply_to_each')]` to decide if the value of the excel column entry is empty. If it is not, append the result to the `relevantDaysVAR` array with:

   ```
   {
     "day": "@{items('Apply_to_each')}",
     "value": "@{variables('excel')[items('Apply_to_each')]}"
   }
   ```
3. **Process the Results** - From here you can do what you need.

---

Attn: Stack Admins, I believe this is a distinctly different answer and warrants the separate nature. I'll happily accept you editing this into the other answer, but I humbly submit that it's a wholly different approach.

[image]