# Power Automate Flow - How to get column names

Tags: expression, power-automate

I have a Power Automate Flow where I want to query table data and return the table data to a chat bot (Power Virtual Agent) including the row data and column names. I know how to access the row data returned but **how can I also get the column header names?** I am connecting to Kusto (Azure Data Explorer) to return tabular data to my flow then I parse the returned values into a string that is formatted with markdown so it can be displayed in table format on the chat bot. This Flow **needs to be dynamic so that it will always work even if there is a different set of columns returned**. Let's say I pass this query to be executed:

```
let TestTable = datatable(ColumnName1:int, ComumnName2:string) 
[
   1, "some string value"
];
TestTable
```

Then the data is returned to the Flow something like this:

```
[
  {
    "ColumnName1": 1,
    "ColumnName2": "some string value"
  }
]
```

When the data is returned I would think I could get the column header names by looping through the results body or value and using an expression something like this:

```
string(fieldName(variables('index')))
```

So that I can parse the field/column header name to a string. This way I can display the row data including column headers dynamically to the user, not just the row data.

```
|---------------------------------|
| ColumnName1 |    ColumnName2    |
|---------------------------------|
| 1           | some string value |
|---------------------------------|
```

I searched online how to get column names like this but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You could use John Liu's xpath()/xml() hack to grab the column names, but I'm not sure how, I might've done it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67295400/filter-json-get-values-which-are-non-empty/67402896#67402896

Comment: It's a shame that there's not a more powerful version of the '_Create HTML table_' connector because that produces a perfect table of the data, nomatter how many of the separate objects have differing values. I tried with this and it's silky: `[ { "ELIOT": 1, "ELIOTTA": "a - some string value" }, { "ELIOT": 123, "ELIOTTA": "b - some string value", "ELIOCINA": true }, { "ELIOT": 321, "ELIOTTA": "c - some string value", "Phil": false, "Collins": "oooh baby", "IsOk": 111 } ]`

Comment: It's a shame that you can't simply return an HTML table to display it in a chat bot

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1 - Use xpath()/xml() to Get Headers

### xpath() Individual Headers

I've plotted this out because it allows you to select and handle each header individually, as opposed to the catchall nature of the normal method.

So, if you use John Liu's `xpath()`/`xml()` hack I mentioned in the comment, but distilling it down to a single expression, you can pick the column names out using this:

```
xpath(xpath(xml(json(concat('{ "root": ', string(variables('arrayVAR')[0]), ' }'))), '/root/*')[0], 'name(/*)')
```

This is assuming that you know how many columns there are, you perform this expression for each column, upping the last number by one each time. However, I'll be editing in a second with what I believe will account for any number of columns.

Essentially, though, to grab the column names it is converting the json into XML, then querying the name value, which is the field name.

This is assuming, also, that there are no null values, which are often simply not included in JSON objects. So you'd need to confirm that the data being sent is all the fields every time, and that they get converted to the JSON even if they're empty.

### xpath() Array of Headers

Using the data example you gave as a basis, and making more entries to test, I've confirmed that this *Select* action will provide an array of all the headers.

*Assume that arrayVAR contains the data.*

1. Set the '**From**' value of the *Select* action to:

   ```
   xpath(xml(json(concat('{ "root": { "columns": ', string(variables('arrayVAR')), ' } }'))), '/root/columns/*')
   ```
2. Set only one Key/Value:

   - '**Key**' - `columnName`
   - '**Value**' - `if(startsWith(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')), '_x003'), if(equals(length(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)'))), 7), substring(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')), 5, 1), concat(substring(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')), 5, 1), substring(string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')), 7))), string(xpath(item(), 'name(/*)')))`

That's it. A full array of headers is yours.

#### Explanation of the If/Then

The reason for such a long if/then statement is in case any of your headers are numbers. When numbers are the value of the field name (and I guess a normal value) in XML it lists them as `_x003#_`. Plus, if you're in the double digits or more, then it will put anything after the first digit after the underscore (`_x003#_#`).

So if your column header is "`5`", the value reported is "`_x0035_`". If your column header is "`555`", then the value reported is "`_x0035_55`".

This expression resolves that.

## Method 2 - Dirty HTML Table Tricks

Basically, using the '*Create HTML table*' action (which neatly draws out all the headers from any fields with values) the flow uses the following expression to parse the header line of that HTML into an array of headers

### Expression

```
split(replace(replace(first(split(body('Create_HTML_table'), variables('headCloseVAR'))), variables('headOpenVAR'), ''), variables('headEndVAR'), ''), variables('headSplitVAR'))
```

I did this using variables to identify what the flow will `split()` and `replace()`, however, a longer (even dirtier) expression will be edited in once I've atoned for the variables.

### Variables

1. **headCloseVAR** - `</tr></thead>` - Defines the end of the header section.

   *The expression will split() on this, and take the first entry in that array.*
2. **headOpenVAR** - `<table><thead><tr><th>` - Start of the header section.

   *This is the first replacement and is simply removed.*
3. **headEndVAR** - `</th>` - End of an individual header.

   *Each of these are also removed as they're redundant.*
4. **headSplitVAR** - `<th>` - Start of an individual header.

   Since the flow removed the first of these if it splits the rest it will create a perfect array of headers.

### Flow

[image: Parsing an HTML Table Header]

### Minimised

You can create a new array using this expression in one go:

```
split(replace(replace(first(split(body('Create_HTML_table'), '</tr></thead>')), '<table><thead><tr><th>', ''), '</th>', ''), '<th>')
```

This worked, but using symbols in function strings is always hit and miss, so I will always test with string variables first. Plus it gives an easier way to understand the logic.

Comment: isn't there some way to grab the json without having to parse to xml first?

Comment: It doesn't seem that way, but I would imagine that the functionality will be there one day.

But, I've worked out a dirty HTML way, which I'll edit in, as an alternative method.

Comment: OK, that's edited in, now. It's actually quite simple to do by parsing the HTML table header with this: `split(replace(replace(first(split(body('Create_HTML_table'), '</tr></thead>')), '<table><thead><tr><th>', ''), '</th>', ''), '<th>')` Which is 3 steps all told.

Comment: OK. Full XML array there now, too. Truth be told, even with the daunting looking if/then nest, it's definitely the way to go, as it's not dependent on anything specific to work out the values.